# Java Generics - Map with Lists of Limited Size

Tags: java, generics

I want to make a class which extends the normal `HashMap<K, V>` class but with some restrictions.

1. The values type `V` is always a `List` of some kind
2. The values inside the `LimitedSizeMap` are always lists with a set limited size.

`LimitedSizeMap.java`

```java
public class LimitedSizeMap<K, V extends List<Object>> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private int limit = 0;

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (this.limit > 0) {
            return super.put(key, value.subList(0, Math.min(value.size(), this.limit)));
        } else {
            return super.put(key, value);
        }
    }

}
```

This code gives me various warnings with my types and such. I tried changing the `List<Object>` to `List<?>` and put `LimitedSizeMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, List<Object>>`instead. But I always get different errors.

What would be the best way to solve this, or how to fix my generics?

Thanks to [@Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner), I've settled for:

```java
public class LimitedSizeMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, List<V>> {
    private final HashMap<K, List<V>> delegateMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Integer limit = null;

    public void setLimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = Math.max(0,limit);
    }

    @Override
    public List<V> put(K key, List<V> value) {
        if (this.limit != null) {
            return this.delegateMap.put(key, value.subList(0, Math.min(value.size(), this.limit)));
        } else {
            return this.delegateMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, List<V>>> entrySet() {
        return this.delegateMap.entrySet();
    }

    public List<V> append(K key, V value) {
        List<V> values = this.delegateMap.getOrDefault(key, new ArrayList<>());

        if (this.limit != null) {
            if (values.size() < this.limit) {
                values.add(value);
            }
        } else {
            values.add(value);
        }

        return this.put(key, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't extend `HashMap`. Use composition.

Comment: `LimitedSizeMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, List<V>>`

Comment: That was my idea aswell, but I thought it's better / easier understandable if I try to keep the typings according to whats actually in there, so I would have `LimitedSizeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` instead of `LimitedSizeMap<Integer, Integer>` and the ladder one would be confused with a Map having just Integers instead of List of Integers as values.

Comment: Maybe change the map name to avoid confusion? Something like LimitedSizeListMap for example. Especially, since it's designed to store lists only, I'd say the problem is not with the genreric parameter, but with the class name.

Comment: @mortom123 note that your current implementation doesn't guarantee the values are shorter than `limit`. You can add more by doing e.g. `map.get(key).add(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. Should I override the  `get` method or are there any other things that would be better suited for this purpose?

Comment: @mortom123 use a limited size list for the values of a standard map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you've got is that `value.subList` returns a `List<Object>`, not a `V`. There is no requirement for the `subList` method to return a `List` of the same type as itself: indeed, you often can't return a list of the same type, because a view of a list is fundamentally not the same as the list itself.

You should declare it as:

```
public class LimitedSizeMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, List<V>> {
```

---

If you *really* want to have the `List` in the `V`, I suppose you can do it by supplying an extra argument to the constructor, which does the "limiting" for you:

```
public class LimitedSizeMap<K, V extends List<Object>> extends HashMap<K, V> {
  private final Function<? super V, ? extends V> trimmer;

  public LimitedSizeMap(Function<? super V, ? extends V> trimmer) { this.trimmer = trimmer; }

  @Override
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    return super.put(key, trimmer.apply(value));
  }
}
```

(or you can make trimmer an abstract method which you have to implement to instantiate the class).

You then just have to work out how you can implement that function. It's easy if your `V` is `List<Object>`; it's less easy otherwise.

I'd say the awkwardness of this far outweights whatever benefit you think you'd have to have the `List`-ness in the type arguments. Honestly, the bigger issue I see with this class is its name implies that the *`Map`* has limited size, not the lists stored in the *values*.

---

I'd also say that extending `HashMap` is a rather dubious thing to do.

I'd recommend extending `AbstractMap<K, List<V>>` and implementing the methods to delegate to a wrapped `HashMap`:

```
public class LimitedSizeMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, List<V>> {
  private final HashMap<K, List<V>> delegate = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (this.limit > 0) {
      return delegate.put(key, value.subList(0, Math.min(value.size(), this.limit)));
    } else {
      return delegate.put(key, value);
    }
  }

  // ... implement the other methods as required: see Javadoc.
}
```